# Como percorrer um elemento por um em um array JS

Tags: javascript, funções, programação-funcional

Fala pessoal, boa tarde.
Eu estou a fazer uma funcao que tem a mesma utilidade do `ANY`.

Qual é a ideia, é saber se tem algum numero menor que o dado na funcao dentro do array, independente se ele esta na primeira ou na ultima posição do array.
Se exister retorna `TRUE`, se não, retorna `FALSE`

O codigo ta assim:

```js
const numerosFora = [1];

function qualquer (num1, func){
 for(let i = 0; i < num1.length; i++){
   for(let i = 0; i < func.length; i++){
     if(num1[i] < func[i]){
        return true
      } else {
         return false
      }
       
      }
    }
   
}

  

console.log(qualquer([1,0],numerosFora))
```

Porem ele so retorna se o numero estiver na primeira posicao, no caso 0.

Comment: A pergunta nao esta clara e nao entendi direito o codigo tambem. Por que nao usa o any?

Comment: @LucasCosta Fala Lucas, boa tarde.

A ideia é eu criar um proprio Any, entendeu?
Posso dizer que é o que ocorrer por tras da palavra `any`, entendeu?

É assim, eu quero saber como eu faco pra passar de um elemento para o outro no array.

EXEMPLO: Saber se existe o numero 3 no array:
Array = [1,2,3,4]

Quero saber como faco pra percorrer ate o 3 e retornar true, entendeu ?
E se retornar false, ele ir pro proximo, ate o ultimo, entendeu?

No meu, ele vai ate so o primeiro e retorna.

Comment: Começa o erro que você tem 2 loops aninhados usando a mesma variável "i", deveria ser duas variáveis diferentes, não?

Answer (score 1):

Se precisar fazer testes em um array para saber se algum de seus elementos satisfazem uma condição use o método [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

O método `some()` aceita uma função callback e a evoca uma vez para cada elemento da array até o momento que essa função callback  retorne true.

```js
/**
 * Procura em um array por um valor menor que o valor indicado. 
 * @param {Array} arr - O array cujo os elementos serão testados contra val.
 * @param {number} val - O valor a ser testado contra os elementos de arr. 
 * @returns {boolean} retorna true quando encontrar em arr um elemento menor que val caso o contrário retorna false.
 */
function menorQue(arr, val) {
  return arr.some((e) => {
    return e < val;
  });
}

let lista = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log(menorQue(lista, 10));

console.log(menorQue(lista, 2));
```

Outra interpretação para o sua pergunta, devido a essa declaração `const numerosFora = [1];`, seria fazer a comparação entre dois arrays e retornando true caso seja encontrado no primeiro array um elemento menor que no segundo.

```js
/**
 * Procura em arr1 por um elemento que seja menor que um dos valores de arr2. 
 * @param {Array} arr1 - Array cujo os elementos serão testados.
 * @param {Array} arr2 - Array cujo os elementos serão testados.
 * @returns {boolean} retorna true quando encontrar em arr1 um elemento menor que qualque um dos elementos de arr2.
 */
function algumMenorQue(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.some((e) => {
    return arr2.some((e1) => {
      return e < e1;
    })
  });
}

let lista = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];


console.log(algumMenorQue(lista, [7, 8, 9]));

console.log(algumMenorQue(lista, [0, 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Os seus `for` possuem problema porque os dois usam a mesma variável `i`, logo, na comparação `num1[i] < func[i]`, os `i` serão sempre do último `for`.

Outra coisa, quando você coloca um `return`, o laço termina, ou seja, os itens restantes da array que por ventura deveriam ser percorridos, não serão mais.

Como você quer apenas verificar se retorna `true` e parar o laço quando isso acontecer, deixe apenas o `return true` no laço (e altere a variável do segundo `for`):

```js
const numerosFora = [1];

function qualquer (num1, func){
  for(let i = 0; i < num1.length; i++){
    for(let x = 0; x < func.length; x++){
      if(num1[i] < func[x]){
        return true;
      }else{
        console.log(false); // apenas como exemplo para mostrar no console
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(qualquer([1,0],numerosFora))
```

Answer (score 0):

Em JavaScript `ES6` seria algo assim:

```
const qualquer = (a, b) => {
  return a.map(item1 => b.map(item2 => item1 < item2 ? true : false));
}

console.log(qualquer([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5])); 

   //Resultado
   //0: (3) [false, true, true]
   //1: (3) [false, true, true]
   //2: (3) [false, false, true]
   //3: (3) [false, false, true]
```